# Talking about yourself in Honorifics [尊敬語]

Tags: nuances, honorifics

Can one talk about themselves in Honorifics? Example:

1. 俺様が宅へお出でになった [I went home]
2. 俺は寿司を召し上がれる [I can eat sushi]
3. 俺は勉強為さってらっしゃる [I am studying]

etc etc

And what instances is it used and the nuance ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is honorific speech ever used in the first person?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/66723/5010) Your sentences are wrong as standard Japanese, but valid as uncommon wordplay.

Comment: Adding on to the linked question, I have never seen even a character who uses 俺様 in modern fiction use honorific expressions for themselves seriously